# Arranging an array in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => object //ticket,
    1 => object //user,
    2 => object //employee,
    3 => object //ticket,
    4 => object //user
    5 => object //ticket,
    6 => object //employee
);
```

From this you can see that the ticket object is always there, whereas the employee and user objects are each optional. What I'd like to do is loop through them and organize them like so:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => object //ticket,
        [1] => object //user,
        [2] => object //employee,
    )
)
```

What I'm having trouble with is since the user and employee are optional I'm not sure how to correctly index based on the above model since occasionally I will hit one that doesn't have an employee or user (in the case that it doesn't, I'd want that index to be null). Any ideas?

EDIT:
Example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        if ($result[$i] instanceof Ticket) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $newResult[$i][] = $result[$i]; //maybe I'm brainfarting, but cannot figure how to identify the last ticket index
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried? That or a theoretical (non-working) example of the code you would like to have would be helpful in understanding exactly what you want to do. code > words :)

Comment: Well, as soon as you hit another ticker, you stop filling the current array and start using the new one.

Comment: The objects are associated based on their ids, the objects themselves are doctrine entities and are being retrieved via a query builder join. If there was some way doctrine could do this automatically, I'd be much happier. But for whatever reason it returns them as separate indexes in the array.

Comment: Why don't you make the subarrays associative, so you don't have to worry about setting indexes to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to your own answer, but doesn't require reindexing `$newResult` when it's done.

```
$newIndex = -1;
$newResult = array();
foreach ($result as $object) {
    if ($object instanceof Ticket) {
        $newResult[] = array($object);
        $newIndex++;
    } else {
        $newResult[$newIndex][] = $object;
    }
}
```

However, your original question mentioned setting the unused elements of the subarrays to `null`. Your answer doesn't do that, so I didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with **instanceof** which class' instance current array element is, and then group it as you prefer :)

Example

```
if( $array[0] instanceof ticket ) {
    // do some magic in here
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Comment: Yup I'm doing that. My problem is how do I lump it in with the last ticket index?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I definitely brainfarted. Sorry for wasting anyones time, here's the loop:

```
$lastTicketIndex = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result) - 1; $i++) {
        if ($result[$i] instanceof Ticket) {
            $newResult[$i][] = $result[$i];
            $lastTicketIndex = $i;
            continue;
        } else {
            $newResult[$lastTicketIndex][] = $result[$i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you're done you should do `$newResult = array_values($newResult)` to renumber the indexes consecutively.